# How to execute handler on click of button

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have to call the handler on click of button its always going in exception case

```
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)
                {   
                     IHandlerService handlerService =
                             (IHandlerService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(
                                 IHandlerService.class);
                         try
                         {
                             handlerService.executeCommand(
                                 DiagnosticsHandler,
                                 null);
                         }
                         catch (Exception e1)
                         {
                             System.out.println(e1.getMessage()+"==getMessage");

                             return;
                         }
```

Comment: This will help you https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommandsAdvanced/article.html

Comment: share more information on DiagnosticsHandler and add exceptions

Comment: Hi @NagarajKandoor thanks for your reply i am trying to call the existing handler directly on click of button . But its not executing  the execute method of handler .What  else information should i share.import
public class DiagnosticsHandler
    extends AbstractHandler
{
}

Comment: can you share stack trace? what exception it's throwing

Comment: Hi  @NagarajKandoor may i have urs some contact no or skype id

Comment: @NagarajKandoor i resolved this issue by simply calling normal class process Like below DiagnosticsHandler xx = new DiagnosticsHandler(); try{ xx.execute(null); }  but issue still persist i have one wizard inside the handler which should open when i call the  handler class but that didnt worked for me in  this case

Comment: @NagarajKandoor Well this code works for me 
IHandlerService handlerService =
                            (IHandlerService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(
                                IHandlerService.class);
     //IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService) getSite().getService(IHandlerService.class);
     try {
         handlerService.executeCommand("avediagnosticsID", null);
         } catch (Exception ex) {
             throw new RuntimeException("add.command not found");
             // Give message
             }
     }

Comment: finally you have resolved your issue.

Comment: @NagarajKandoor Thanks for your support yes my issue has been resolved